# Installing Audiere Module on Python 2.7 Windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have downloaded the module from sourceforge. [audiere-1.9.4-win32](http://kaz.dl.sourceforge.net/project/audiere/audiere/1.9.4/audiere-1.9.4-win32.zip)

The unzipped folder has the following folders:

-bin

-bindings

-doc

-include

-lib

The Bindings folder includes a file called audiere.pyd and an installation instruction which says:

> Into the Windows distribution of Python 2.2:
>    Copy audiere.dll and audiere.pyd into your Python22 directory (or
>    perhaps Python22/DLLs, depending on your system).

I tried copying both files to:

-python 2.7/

-python 2.7/DLL

-python 2.7 /LIb/site-packages/ directory but

```
import audiere
```

still gives a import error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import audiere
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I am sure this is nothing to do with python 2.2 versus python 2.7 because people have successfully used audiere on 2.7 without any modification.

How do I install audiere on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [pyglet](http://pyglet.org/). This library has the capability to play using external library called [Avbin](http://code.google.com/p/avbin). 
Simple example of how to use:

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.resource.media('music.mp3')
music.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

If you have some problems with avbin, put the dll in the same directory of your code and insert this two lines before "pyglet.resource.media('music.mp3')":

```
pyglet.lib.load_library('avbin')
pyglet.have_avbin=True
```